# How do you get infected with HIV?

Tags: disease-transmission, sti, hiv

If someone has unprotected sex with a woman who had other sexual partners before will that cause HIV?

Comment: You didn't ask about this, but there's more to worry about here than HIV - herpes, chlamydia, HPV, etc....

Comment: @CareyGregory :-D though, on a more serious note, of course, this behavior also puts that husband at risk... And as I mentioned above, HIV is hardly the only concern

Comment: ... Definitely one of the weirder questions out there. Didn't you have basic education on such matters when you were at school? I don't think any modern person would still be told that if you simply have direct sex/sex out of marriage then you'd have AIDS. That would be ridiculous. Whether that person is married has zero impact on whether he/she has AIDS/STDs or not. They're two completely separate matters. Just do some tests if you're still afraid. That's the only way to tell. But normally I'd not worry very much.

Comment: @Pilot Lol no you don't need to feel sorry about that. Sorry if what I said came across as a kind of rude to you. It's just that it's good to have some knowledge about sex, even if your schools were a bit conservative and didn't talk about that much. In any case, the percentage of population with AIDS is really small and countless people have sex every day, and they certainly don't worry too much when doing it. So it should be fine for you as well.

Comment: Should the title of this read 'infected' instead of 'affected' ? I wasn't 100% sure I would be changing your original intent.

Comment: Is the woman in question infected with HIV or not?

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/5286/7951

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What should I take care of while sleeping with another woman to protect her against AIDS?**

1. Get tested and go see you doctor. [CDC.gov:](http://www.cdc.gov/hiv/basics/testing.html)

   > No HIV test can detect HIV immediately after infection. If you think
   >   you’ve been exposed to HIV, talk to your health care provider as soon
   >   as possible.

   It takes 3-12 weeks after initial exposure for testing to be able to detect antibodies. Contacting your doctor can help you by him/her explaining risk and possibly giving you medication that can decrease risk. Both get tested so your status is known.
2. Abstainng or utilize protective sex methods. Abstaining can cut out all possibilities of exposure, unless blood pathogens are involved. Safe Sex with condoms, etc simply decrease risks.

   [Risk-Reducing and HIV](http://wwwn.cdc.gov/hivrisk/)
3. Notify her of your exposure. This can help her be aware of the possible repercussions and prepare for what testing she may need.

---

**I am afraid if I have sex with my wife it will cause her to have AIDS?**

1. You could give her HIV, [which is the virus that leads to AIDS](https://www.aids.gov/hiv-aids-basics/hiv-aids-101/what-is-hiv-aids/).
2. Follow through on doctor visits and testing to confirm whether or not you were infected.

Comment: This answer seems to focus on how to protect a woman against HIV/AIDS from the perspective of a man who sleeps with her. However, the question seems to ask about getting HIV from a non-virgin woman (without mentioning, whether or not she is infected). Maybe you could expand your answer to cover this as well.

Comment: I edited the misleading statement about not giving her AIDS because she'd have to have HIV first. Colloquially people don't differentiate between HIV and AIDS, so he is most likely asking if he could give her HIV, not AIDS specifically.  It's dangerous because it insinuated that an HIV-infected person's sexual partner is safe from getting HIV, when they are at extremely high risk each time they have intercourse.